# Error while installing tensorflow js on node using npm

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm, tensorflow.js

I ran into this issue while using npm to install tensorflowjs according to the documentation.

https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup

I made sure I am using a elevated powershell and have vs c++ redistributable 2017. What seems to be the issue?

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

> @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.3.2 install C:\Users\JC\Downloads\CSE535_local\hw2\posenet_nodejs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
> node scripts/install.js

CPU-windows-1.3.2.zip
* Downloading libtensorflow
[==============================] 11885962/bps 100% 0.0s
[==============================] 2734106/bps 100% 0.0s
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v4/1.3.2/CPU-windows-1.3.2.zip
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.3.2 and node@12.10.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:196:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\JC\\Downloads\\CSE535_local\\hw2\\posenet_nodejs\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v4\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\JC\\Downloads\\CSE535_local\\hw2\\posenet_nodejs\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v4" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=4" "--node_napi_label=napi-v4"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\JC\Downloads\CSE535_local\hw2\posenet_nodejs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\JC\Downloads\CSE535_local\hw2\posenet_nodejs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v4\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=C:\Users\JC\Downloads\CSE535_local\hw2\posenet_nodejs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v4 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=4 --node_napi_label=napi-v4' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JC\Downloads\CSE535_local\hw2\posenet_nodejs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\JC\\Downloads\\CSE535_local\\hw2\\posenet_nodejs\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\JC\Downloads\CSE535_local\hw2\posenet_nodejs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm WARN @tensorflow-models/posenet@2.1.2 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@~1.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow-models/posenet@2.1.2 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@~1.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN pose_net_trails@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.3.2
updated 1 package and audited 400 packages in 8.139s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: You have some warnings but the package `@tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.3.2` is downloaded, is it not ?

Comment: I don't think so. The package may be downloaded but never installed. When I rerun the command, it will download it again

Comment: After the command can you paste your package.json ?